# Why am I not able to downgrade Rxjs?

Tags: angular, npm, rxjs

The title says everything. My current version is rxjs 6.1.0. arget is 5.5.4. This is all I tried to downgrade the package:

npm -v rxjs
6.1.0

```
npm install rxjs@5.5.4 --save
```

+ rxjs@5.5.4
updated 1 package and audited 7535 packages in 18.429s

```
npm -v rxjs
```

6.1.0

```
npm install rxjs@5.5.4
```

+ rxjs@5.5.4

```
npm -v rxjs
```

6.1.0

```
npm install rxjs@5
```

+ rxjs@5.5.11
updated 1 package and audited 7535 packages in 22.66s

```
npm -v rxjs
```

6.1.0

**package.json**

```
....

"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "5.5.4", <----------
"zone.js": "^0.8.19"
....
```

->

```
npm install
```

updated 1 package and audited 7535 packages in 13.378s

```
npm -v rxjs
```

6.1.0

What else can I do, to downgrade this package?

Comment: Remove `node_modules` folder. Clean chache. Install again

Comment: try install `rxjs-compat`, then you don't need downgrade.

Comment: 1 comment doesnt work
Observable.timer... it doesn't exist after rxjs 5.5.4

Comment: after making changes to package.json  `"rxjs": "5.5.4",` execute `npm prune` and then execute `npm install`

Comment: nope, unfortunately not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the **rxjs version 6.1.0** installed globally on your machine.

1. Run to clean npm cache on your machine:
   `npm cache clean --force`
2. Run this to install it globally: 
   `npm i rxjs@5.5.4 -g`

Try this command to check version of rxjs : `npm list -g | find "rxjs"`

Comment: Actually `npm -v rxjs` is showing you the version of npm not rxjs version.

Comment: Try this command to check version of rxjs : `npm list -g | find "rxjs" `

Comment: You are a Legend